# Rails 5 - How to migrate foreign keys to PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

> A travel expense must have information on which cost center paid for
>   the ticket, and which cost center paid for the traveling costs.

I've ran the following migration, attempting to create two foreign keys to map to `cost_centers`, which worked fine for **SQLite**:

```
  def change
    add_reference :expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center, index: true
    add_reference :expense_travels, :travel_cost_center, index: true

    add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :air_ticket_cost_center_id
    add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :travel_cost_center_id
  end
```

this, however, doesn't work for **PostgreSQL**:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "air_ticket_cost_centers" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "expense_travels" ("id" serial primary key, "expense_id" integer, "person_id" integer, "manager" character varying, "travel_type_id" integer, "air_ticket_amount" decimal(15,2), "air_ticket_cost_center_id" integer, "travel_amount" decimal(15,2), "travel_cost_center_id" integer, "total_amount" decimal(15,2), "start_date" date, "end_date" date, "itinerary" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_51368cd47f"
FOREIGN KEY ("expense_id")
REFERENCES "expenses" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4c8cafa3f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("person_id")
REFERENCES "people" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_41906a97fa"
FOREIGN KEY ("travel_type_id")
REFERENCES "travel_types" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_c4144cce64"
FOREIGN KEY ("air_ticket_cost_center_id")
REFERENCES "air_ticket_cost_centers" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8d209073b1"
FOREIGN KEY ("travel_cost_center_id")
REFERENCES "travel_cost_centers" ("id")
)
```

It attempts to set **FOREIGN KEY** ("**air_ticket_cost_center_id**") as **REFERENCE** of "**air_ticket_cost_centers**" ("id"), which should have been a reference to **cost_centers** instead.

TLDR: On PostgreSQL, in order to reference the same existing table twice on another table without conflicts, how can I set my migration?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** - Including Full Stack Trace

```
== 20170109120056 AddCostCentersToExpenseTravels: migrating ===================
-- add_column(:expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0014s
-- add_column(:expense_travels, :travel_cost_center_id, :integer)
   -> 0.0007s
-- add_foreign_key(:expense_travels, :cost_centers, {:column=>:air_ticket_cost_center_id})
   -> 0.0000s
-- add_foreign_key(:expense_travels, :cost_centers, {:column=>:travel_cost_center_id})
   -> 0.0000s
-- add_index(:expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center_id)
   -> 0.0030s
-- add_index(:expense_travels, :travel_cost_center_id)
   -> 0.0033s
== 20170109120056 AddCostCentersToExpenseTravels: migrated (0.0091s) ==========

  db:schema:dump -->   0.250000   0.010000   0.260000 (  0.267062)
  db:_dump -->   0.250000   0.010000   0.260000 (  0.267429)
  db:migrate -->   0.710000   0.070000   0.780000 (  1.101759)
  db:abort_if_pending_migrations -->   0.040000   0.010000   0.050000 (  0.040145)
  db:seed -->   0.170000   0.020000   0.190000 (  0.215987)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "air_ticket_cost_centers" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "expense_travels" ("id" serial primary key, "expense_id" integer, "person_id" integer, "manager" character varying, "travel_type_id" integer, "air_ticket_amount" decimal(15,2), "air_ticket_cost_center_id" integer, "travel_amount" decimal(15,2), "travel_cost_center_id" integer, "total_amount" decimal(15,2), "start_date" date, "end_date" date, "itinerary" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_51368cd47f"
FOREIGN KEY ("expense_id")
  REFERENCES "expenses" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4c8cafa3f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("person_id")
  REFERENCES "people" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_41906a97fa"
FOREIGN KEY ("travel_type_id")
  REFERENCES "travel_types" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_c4144cce64"
FOREIGN KEY ("air_ticket_cost_center_id")
  REFERENCES "air_ticket_cost_centers" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8d209073b1"
FOREIGN KEY ("travel_cost_center_id")
  REFERENCES "travel_cost_centers" ("id")
)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:97:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:283:in `create_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/home/yadayada/workspace/yadayada/sources/db/migrate/20161201174226_create_expense_travels.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:in `with_advisory_lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-benchmark-1.0.0/lib/rake/benchmark.rb:8:in `block in execute_with_benchmark'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-benchmark-1.0.0/lib/rake/benchmark.rb:7:in `execute_with_benchmark'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Let me see if a understand: what you need is 2 new columns in your expense_travels table (air_ticket_cost_center_id, travel_cost_center_id). Both of these columns must have an index and a FK constraint to the table cost_centers. Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly right @DarioBarrionuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence `add_reference :expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center` will try to find a table named **expense_travels** and another one named **air_ticket_cost_center** and then create a reference between them. That's why you get **relation "air_ticket_cost_centers" does not exist**

Let's try this:

```
add_reference :expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center, table: :cost_centers, index: true
add_reference :expense_travels, :travel_cost_center, table: :cost_centers, index: true

add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :air_ticket_cost_center_id
add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :travel_cost_center_id
```

If that still doesn't work, you can't go wrong by splitting up the steps:

```
add_column :expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center_id, :integer
add_column :expense_travels, :travel_cost_center_id, :integer

add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :air_ticket_cost_center_id
add_foreign_key :expense_travels, :cost_centers, column: :travel_cost_center_id

add_index :expense_travels, :air_ticket_cost_center_id
add_index :expense_travels, :travel_cost_center_id
```

Comment: Hello Dario! I've attempted both approaches, but it still leads me to the same error :( on the second approach, I've also added the _id to the add_column statements. I don't know why is it looking for a table with the same name of the columns instead of the table we are specifically assigning them to

Comment: Of course, the columns to add with `add_column` statement MUST be _id, I edited my answer. Are you completely sure the error is being raised in this particular migration? If you run the second version of the migration Postgres should be able to create the columns, so where do you get the error? when adding the foreign keys?

Comment: Exactly, the fields are created normally: the issue pops up during the constraint assignment, trying to reference "air_ticket_cost_centers" as a table, even if it was never mentioned in that way during the migration, just as fields with "_id". It looks like it's trying to force the field into a convention or something, I'm trully out of ideas here. Could it be some issue on AR itself? Have you done something along the lines lately? I've read that it worked on SQLite because "SQLite isn't as strict as PG on FKs", which didn't make sense at all to me.

Comment: Hmm... as far as I can tell, that output seems to have run AddCostCentersToExpenseTravels successfully. However, you seem to have the error in 20161201174226_create_expense_travels.rb, so I'm a little bit confused right now. Can you check that migration and see if you're not trying to reference the ghost table air_ticket_cost_centers?

Comment: Damn... I never check that huge stack trace, always the top only. The issue was there all along, there was a `t.belongs_to :air_ticket_cost_center, foreign_key: true` which was obviously causing that check for the ghost table. Feeling really stupid, but thankful for your help :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help ;)